# How to set tags/keyword for image in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have image website.
Image's detail is saved with it in mysql

```
Id| path  image    weight  like  date          alt  user   admin  tag
01  aaa/  xys.jpg   10gm    25   25-12-2017    xxx   usr1  adm1   nature,wild
```

I am saving tags in tag row and when i want to sort some image i search for tag in whole "Tag" array .
there are many different tags for all tables.
Any idea for better option than this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tags and Images have a Many to Many relationship, which means a tag can have many images and an image can have many tags.
Therefore you should create two more tables to handle that structure.

```
images - id, path, etc..
tags - id, name
image_tags - image_id, tag_id
```

that way to do a search by a tag you'll be able to join those table and it's an easy job.

Comment: Sorry to say but there will be no relation in my website. Every table will have a different tag.

Comment: What do you mean? This is just for the images table

Comment: I have jewellery catalogue website. In Gold ring design table there will be tag like , Without stone , with stone , round ring or oval size ring .

Comment: So? This is the way to do what you are looking for.
If every tag has only one single image then it's a one to many relationship and you can save the image_id in the tags table. But that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I think I understand your confusion, for the gold ring table for example you will create a gold_ring_tags table, it doesn't matter different table has different tags in that case, the tags can be saved on one table.
Or you can create a table called gr_tags and the relation would be gold_ring_gr_tags. But I really don't think it's necessary